# Two classes differ only in an inner class. How can they be derived from the same base class by the less effort?

Tags: c#, inheritance

Consider a class  `C` where `C.Sub1.Sub2.Sub3` is defined,
and another class `D` where `D.Sub1.Sub2.Sub3` is also defined, but `Sub3` has a different type than in class `C`. E.g `Sub3`  in `C` is a `Dictionary`, while `Sub3` in `D` is a `string`.

Suppose that `Sub1` and `Sub2` are complicated structures, and the difference between `C` and `D` is only in `Sub3`.

I want to derive `C` and `D` from the same base class, say `B`. I know, that I can make this in the following way:

```
class B
{
 ...
    public T1 Sub1 { get; set; }
 ...
}
class T1
{
 ...
    public T2 Sub2 { get; set; }
 ...
}
class T2
{
 ...
    public object Sub3 { get; set; }
 ...
}
```

---

```
class C : B
{
    public new T1_C Sub1 { get; set; }
}
class T1_C : T1
{
    public new T2_C Sub2 { get; set; }
}
class T2_C : T2
{
    public new Dictionary<string, string> Sub3 { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
class D : B
{
    public new T1_D Sub1 { get; set; }
}
class T1_D : T1
{
    public new T2_D Sub2 { get; set; }
}
class T2_D : T2
{
    public new string Sub3 { get; set; }
}
```

Cannot it be made by less effort somehow ? Are `T1_C`, `T2_C`, `T1_D` and `T2_D` really unavoidable?

Comment: you could also not use inheritance at all, just use subs and interfaces. then you can make one interface that dictates sub 1 + sub 2, one that forces sub 2 + sub 3 etc

Comment: "Union Type" is the name of the concept you are after for Sub3. C# does not have them, but you can get poorman's union types using marker interfaces and pattern matching. If you want an out-of-the-box solution, your best bet is to use generics as Nico has said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the types generic:

```
class B <InnerType>
{
 ...
    public T1<InnerType> Sub1 { get; set; }
 ...
}
class T1 <InnerType>
{
 ...
    public T2<InnerType> Sub2 { get; set; }
 ...
}
class T2<InnerType>
{
 ...
    public InnerType Sub3 { get; set; }
 ...
}
```

And then

```
class C : B<Dictionary<string, string>> { ... }
class D : B<string>  { ... }
```

Comment: this is also a good idea, altho a little bit hard to refactor. If you add a new generic type here you would have to change all collections where this is used and all the signatures.